# Native Browser Promise Invokes Itself After Loading

Tags: javascript, promise

I am using the native baked in promise of the browsers....this particular one is chrome atm.

My issue is the promise invokes as soon as it loads.... before I ever invoke it manually. This is causing errors since the dom is not ready yet.

Why does this promise invoke itself as soon as the js file is loaded?

```
var noNameFoo = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  rippleElement = document.getElementById('ripple-element');
  toolbar = document.querySelector('#main-toolbar');
  headerName = document.getElementById('name-title');
  panel = document.getElementById('dad');
  drawer = document.querySelector('paper-drawer-panel');
  mainPanelContent = document.getElementById('mainPanelContent');

  //elements is not routing list, routing list is elementList
  var elements = [rippleElement, toolbar, headerName, panel, 
      drawer, mainPanelContent];

  console.log(elements);
  var completed = elements.every(function(el) {
    if (el !== null && typeof el !== 'undefined' && el.nodeType === 1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });

  if (completed) {
    resolve();
  } else {
    var errMsg = 'error in querying elements';
    reject(errMsg);
  }
});
```

Comment: What did you expect? You write some code, put it in a file and it executes. Promises work no different than other code. You can still chain on to it with `.then()` and `.catch()`.

Comment: What do you mean? function foo() {} doesn't invoke until I do `foo()`

Comment: Are you missing the fact that you are declaring a `new Promise` and not a function? Perhaps you wanted `var noNameFoo = function noNameFoo(){ /*some code that returns a promise*/ }`?

Comment: Ok, makes sense...I used to use the defer() method which I would do foo().then(). But mozilla did away with defer()

Comment: `mozilla did away with defer()` a long time ago in a release far far away

Comment: A Promise isn't an action. It's the *result* of the action. "Invoking a Promise" makes no more sense than saying "Invoking a number" or "Invoking a boolean".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Promise is a proxy for a value. You're calling the promise constructor - and that code executes. Just like if you write `[alert(5)]` it will run the alert immediately.

A promise is not an action - it is just the value. If you want the action - wrap it in a function.